# how to change background color of UITableViewCell from red to orange to green smoothly

Tags: ios, ios7, core-animation, gradient, uicolor

How can I change the background color of a UITableViewCell from red => orange => green depending on a signal strength input ( between 0.0 to 1.0 ). 
My app get the signal strength every second, I would like to change the whole background color of the cell as the signal strength changes. suppose when the signal strength changes from 0.0 to 0.3 the background color should change from Red => Red + Orange (red + orange mixed) => Orange. How can I mix the colors to get results ?

Comment: It's a simple `UIView animateWithDuration..` problem, with nesting. UIView animation will take care of color mixing.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Can you please explain a bit more, I am no used to the animation and gradient in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Works as expected on my side.

`yourCell` here is the cell whose `backgroundColor` you wish to change.

It's a basic sample code. You will have to modify this for different state changes according to your needs.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{

                     yourCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                      animations:^{

                                          yourCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

                                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                                           animations:^{

                                                               yourCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                                                           }];

                                      }];

                 }];
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem... the problem is I need the intermediate colors to stay and change smoothly depending on the change in signal strength.

Comment: Is it a single cell whose color you want to change, or more than one cell?